# 4th Table doesn't align to bottom

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hta

I'm creating a little HTA application and I need to make the layout using `table` tag. Because HTA uses the old IE rendering engine, it's the only way I can make things work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
        <title>0nurky Hacks</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    </head>
<body>
<table id="head">
    <td>#head</td>
</table>

<table id="menu" align="left">
    <td>#menu</td>
</table>

<table id="aside" align="left">
    <td>#aside</td>
</table>

<table id="foot" valign="left">
    <td>#foot</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

table#head {
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
    height:15.5%;
    color:#fff;
}

table#head td {
    padding-left:3%;
    padding-right:3%;
}

table#menu {
    background:gray;
    width:25%;
}

table#aside {
    background:lightgray;
    width:75%;
}

table#foot {
    background:darkgray;
    width:100%;
    height:8.9%;
}
```

So basically, I've put `align="left"` on every `table` tag instead of `table#head`.

As you can see the fourth `table` doesn't align to bottom even though it's `width`
is 100%, but instead it aligns to left, touching the third `table`.

~ I know people will say, why use HTA when you can do it via node.js and with everything else. ~
I'm making this for my friend so yeah.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: image link you shared is dead, also i don't think sharing the image will help solving the problem.It's better to share the html.and css

Comment: I've added the code now :)

Comment: `td`s can't be direct children of a `table`, you need to add `tr` elements accordingly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy.

add this to your CSS code:

```
.jump {
    display:inline-block;
    height:25px;
}
```

...and this to your HTML code before 4th table:

```
<div class="jump"></div>
```

And there you go, this is how it looks like:[image: layout]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for? push the 4th table to bottom of the page?

ALSO `align=""`

Attribute definitions

> align = left|center|right|justify [CI]
>
> #### Deprecated. This attribute specifies the horizontal alignment of its element with respect to the surrounding context. Possible values:
>
> left: text lines are rendered flush left.
>
> center: text lines are centered.
>
> right: text lines are rendered flush right.
>
> justify: text lines are justified to both margins.
>
> The default depends on the base text direction. For left to right text, the default is align=left, while for right to left text, the default is align=right.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

table#head {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15.5%;
  color: #fff;
}

table#head td {
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

table#menu {
  background: gray;
  width: 25%;
}

table#aside {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 75%;
}

table#foot {
  text-align: center;
  background: darkgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.9%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
    <title>0nurky Hacks</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="head">
      <td>#head</td>
    </table>

    <table id="menu" align="left">
      <td>#menu</td>
    </table>

    <table id="aside" align="left">
      <td>#aside</td>
    </table>

    <table id="foot" valign="left">
      <td>#foot</td>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Something similar but Not exactly to the BOTTOM. I mean, align the 4th table below these three up there. Not exactly to the bottom :)

Something like:
[HEAD]
[M][AS]
[FOOT]

Comment: So what is the exact issue here is that, the #foot table appears to right with 100% width. Instead of appearing to bottom, please see the example image right next http://i.imgur.com/L83Leyk.jpg